# Upgrade to Newtonsoft.json version 12.0.0 breaks the Connect-AzAccount command

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-remoting

I am executing a simple PowerShell script from c# and the script is as below

```
[pscredential]$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('admin.onmicrosoft.com', $(ConvertTo-SecureString 'Iamnotright' -AsPlainText -Force))

Connect-AzAccount -Credential $credential

get-module
```

Due to some reason I have upgraded the Newtonsoft.json dll to the version 12.0.3 from the previous 11.0.2. My code has suddenly started to give the below error after the upgrade of Newtonsoft.json, which I am unable to resolve.

```
Connect-AzAccount: Method 'get_SerializationSettings' in type
'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient'
from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Clients.ResourceManager,
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
does not have an implementation. At line:9 char: 1
+ Connect-AzAccount -Credential $credential
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], TypeLoadException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId: System.TypeLoadException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand
```

If I degrade the Newtonsoft.json back to version 11.0.2, the script starts to work fine.

Any insight into this will be appreciated. It is a compulsion now for me, to use the Newtonsoft.json 12 version instead of 11, and I can't degrade it back.

Looks like this has been an annoying problem and is posted here as well
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9728

Comment: Does old code still work?  When was last time you used the code?  It looks like you are having an issue connecting to the database.  The old code may also fail.

Comment: The old code is the code that has the degraded version of Newtonsoft.json DLL(version 11.0.2) and it works absolutely fine. Here is the problem I am talking about.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9728